# Problem exporting vector graphics (PDF) in Mathematica Notebook Front-End using remote kernel on linux

Tags: front-end, export, pdf-format, kernel, remote-access

I'm not being able to export vector graphics images (especially PDF) in a Mathematica Notebook Front-End in Windows 8.1 using a remote kernel on a Linux server.

I can, however, export Raster Image Formats without any problem.

One interesting thing to point out is the fact that when accessing the server directly via ssh command line, launching Mathematica kernel and executing the same `Export` command, it works fine.

Mathematica 11.3 is the version being used on both: Front-end and Back-end PCs.

**Example of a Mathematica Notebook:**

```
SetDirectory["/home/results"]

plt = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]

Export["test.gif", plt]  (*Works fine*)

Export["test.jpg", plt]  (*Works fine*)

Export["test.png", plt]  (*Works fine*)

Export["test.pdf", plt]  (*Does not work*)

Export["test.eps", plt]  (*Does not work*)
```

Comment: Same here. Did you find a solution?